# Performance issues AWS - Docker - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have an application deployed with docker on an EC2 instance: t3a.xlarge.
My application is using 7 different containers (cf image docker-ps.png):

- A Django App, as an API (using python 3.6)
- An Angular Application (using Angular2+)
- A memcached server
- A cerbot (using letsencrypt to automatically renew my SSL
  certificats)
- A Nginx, used as a reverse proxy to serve my angular application and
  my Django API
- A Postgres database
- A Pgadmin in order to mananage my database

The issues happen when we send a push notification to our users using Firebase (around 42,000 users). The API is not responding during a certain amount of time: from 1min to 6min. 
The Django API use the webserver Gunicorn (https://gunicorn.org/ ) with this configuration:

```
 gunicorn xxxx_api.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:80 --max-requests 500 --max-requests-jitter 50 --enable-stdio-inheritance -k gevent --workers=16  -t 80
```

The server or the container never crashed. When I check the metrics, we never use more than 60% of the CPU. Here is a screenshot of some metrics when the notification has been sent: https://ibb.co/Mc0v7R1

Is it because we are using too much bandwidth than our instance allowed us to use? Or should I use another AWS service?

Comment: Memory ? Did you monitor

Comment: @ArunK what is the name of the memory metric?

Comment: Memory utilisation metrics not collected

Comment: According to ibb.co/xCWxVJf you shared, your API uses 296% of CPU :-) API should have throttling - have limits on number of requests it handles. You need to monitor application and Gunicorn level logging to understand if supported connections are enough or if there is some other issue.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev 296% means the API is using 3 cores right? Which is correct for me

Comment: @nickolay.laptev it has to be 3 cores because when I monitor my instance on AWS, the CPU utilization never reach more than 80%

Answer (score 0):

Memory utilisation metrics are not captured for ec2 instances since OS level metrics are not available to AWS. You can collect custom metrics by your self

Reference:
https://awscloudengineer.com/create-custom-cloudwatch-metrics-centos-7/

Comment: I set up the different metrics, I'll keep you updated: https://ibb.co/KLFrpLv
If it's because there is not enough Memory, I should change my instance to get more memory? Or should I monitor which container uses a lot of memory and put it on a different instance? (cost-wise)

Comment: So I monitored the memory and nothing to worry about. But I check "docker stats" when we sent a push notification and here is the result: https://ibb.co/xCWxVJf
With a 80% CPU usage. Does it mean that my instance has not enough CPU?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about the design, you could try sending your push notifications as an async queue using things like SNS & SQS (it's AWS Way) or Celery & Redis (it's a traditional way)

If you choose the traditional way this post could help you
https://blog.devartis.com/sending-real-time-push-notifications-with-django-celery-and-redis-829c7f2a714f

Comment: Sorry I edited my post, we are using mobile notification with Firebase

Answer (score 0):

I think Its because of queuing Http requests to firebase. I believe that you are sending 42000 firebase requests in a loop. I/O calls are blocking in nature. if you are running the Django app in single thread using gunicorn. these 42000 http calls will block the new calls until they are finished. they will stay in queue until the connection is alive or the requests are within nginx threshold. I don't think 42000 push notifications will exhaust memory and processing unless payload is too high.